# Migrate SBS 2003 to 2008 New Domain

Tags: exchange, migration, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs-2003

Our company is currently sharing a SBS 2003 with another company in the same building, we are moving out and would like to take our exchange accounts with us. We have a new SBS 2008 setup with a new domain and need some way to migrate the exchange accounts from the 2003 to the 2008 small business servers.

I've been searching but have only found tutorials on how to do this on the same domian, so any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a dozen or two mailboxes, I'd just export them from the old server, create a whole new AD & Exchange setup on the new server and import the e-mail to the new server.

Moving mailboxes like you describe is quite difficult. Using [ExMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=429163ec-dcdf-47dc-96da-1c12d67327d5&displaylang=en) is pretty easy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I looked at exmerge but it says it only works with 2003 so I can get the emails out but how do I get them back in ? Thanks

Comment: It only says that because at the time the program was written Ex2003 was the newest version. I haven't used it on SBS2008, but it works on Ex2007 Ent. Worst case, the export creates a PST, which every version of Outlook can import too.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting to PST works as well, though it does mess up the last modified date so archiving no longer archives mails as expected.